# Nginx reverse proxy with SSL to a server already using HTTPS

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I have a small setup where I host a simple website on a raspberry pi with ddns. It was HTTPS enabled using a letsencrypt certificate. Now I wanted to create a second website, and since they're both pretty lightweight, I wanted to serve it from the same raspberry pi. I got another ddns hostname, another set of certificates, put them behind an nginx reverse proxy, and everything's working just peachy.

The thing I was wondering is - my first server was already using HTTPS, and then I put it behind the nginx reverse proxy, where nginx was configured to use ssl too. From my nginx `.conf` file:

```
server {
    server_name mysmallwebsite.ddns.net;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/mysmallwebsitecert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/mysmallwebsitkey.pem;
...
}
```

So both nginx and the app it relays connections to use the same cert/key.

Is something like this okay and is there any harm in that? Would there be any noticeable performance improvement if I downgraded my app to use plain HTTP and leave the encryption to nginx?

Comment: It depends how secure you need the link between the reverse proxy and the application server. But if you use `http` for the upstream link, you avoid having to negotiate two separate SSL connections for every request.

Comment: Noted. In that case I think I'll be dropping the `https` from the application server, at least in this scenario, and leave it to nginx. Thanks!